# Why isn't MSBuild with TFS 2017 copying content items in to the $(Build.BinariesDirectory) directory?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have upgraded my company's TFS from 2013 to 2017.  We still have our old XAML build definitions but are moving to the new JSON templates.

Most of the build definitions are working fine but some don't act like the former XAML definitions.  I get all of the compiled assemblies in the $(Build.BinariesDirectory) folder but if I have a csproj that has Content items set to CopyAlways, they get copied to $(Build.SourcesDirectory), but they do not get copied into the $(Build.BinariesDirectory) for MSBuild. [Project set up in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiBt6.png)

When building the old XAML build definitions they are copied to the bin directory fine: [Build agent with the copied content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTDCt.png)

I have tried changing versions from 15 to the older 14 which still did not resolve this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean using the vNext build system, then you can add below msbuild arguments in the `MSBuild Arguments` area of the **Visual Studio Build** or **MsBuild** task to get the target files copied to the binaries directory.:

```
 /p:OutputPath=$(Build.BinariesDirectory)
```

**Note:** The output is going to the \b\ folder, as the value of the variable `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)` is something like `c:\agent\_work\1\b`.

> Build.BinariesDirectory :
>
> The local path on the agent you can use as an output folder for
>   compiled binaries. For example: `c:\agent\_work\1\b`.
>
> ***Source: [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#predefined-variables)***

[image]

Comment: @Chris Judah Have you resolved the issue by the answer? any update?

Comment: It was the fact that the OutputPath wasn't being set.  It took me a while to notice it.  We had someone else migrate some Build Definitions to vNext and just copying and pasting parameters, which in this case, got excluded.